# Using media queries with Slick & Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, media-queries, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I'm using a [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider on my WordPress homepage. I am gathering the images for the slider via Word Press' Advanced Custom Fields. I'm curious if it's possible to change the slider image based on breakpoints. Keep in mind that these images are coming from the server, so I need them on page load. If this isn't possible with Slick can you suggest an alternative?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    autoplay: true
 });
});
```

Comment: Is setting a `data-src-small="url-of-smaller-image.png"` and replacing the src with it with jquery not an option?

Comment: @usgmr Do you  mean load all of the images on page load and do a swap via jQuery when specific breakpoints are hit? Not a bad idea at all... Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Although you don't necessarily have to load it all since that would impact page load. Using html5 `data` attribute to store url of other sizes then change it using jquery would do it. Additionally, you can use slick.js's lazy load function if you can so the default images won't be loaded until needed.